# What the meaning of "impatience" in Bellman equation?

Tags: dynamic-programming

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation#A_dynamic_decision_problem):

> **A dynamic decision problem**
>
> ... Finally, we assume **impatience**, represented by a discount factor $0 < \beta < 1$

What the meaning of "impatience"? I can't understand even if I read https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/impatience.

Comment: Do you want the _mean_ (average) or _meaning_ (definition) of impatience?

Comment: @J.G. Meaning, sorry English is not my native language.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_preference

Comment: @JacobManaker "The neighbor's dog barks every night, which makes me **impatient**. ", is the "impatience" here same meaning to my question?

Comment: @JoeHuang: Probably not.  Impatience in your sentence is an emotion (I think?  It's a weird think to say).  In the Bellman equation, we need some way to model the tradeoff between bad solutions now and good solutions later.  This is called "impatience" to give us intuition for what it's measuring, but it's not predicated on any psychological sensation.

Comment: @JacobManaker Thanks. English is more difficult than math.